# Where is Meshlabserver.exe in 2020.12

Tags: meshlab

Could it be, that 2020.12 (Windows 64bit) is missing the meshlabserver.exe?

Or do I miss something?

I already reinstalled MeshLab but still no server to be found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meshlabserver is discontinued. From [meshlab.net](https://www.meshlab.net)

> MeshLab 2020.12 has been released. With this version, we dismiss
> meshlabserver in favour of PyMeshLab, our new Python library for mesh
> batch processing using MeshLab filters.

You can still execute your old .mlx filter scripts using a simple python script like this :

```py
import pymeshlab as ml
ms = ml.MeshSet()
ms.load_new_mesh('input.ply')
ms.load_filter_script('my_script.mlx')
ms.apply_filter_script()
ms.save_current_mesh('output.ply')
```

If you really need the meshlabserver executable, try one older package.

Comment: There is no need for the meshlabserver per se, just a way automate the editing of a mesh, which are always the same steps. Thank you.

Comment: I've got a lot of files that I want to apply the same filter to. With the exe it would have been possible to simply create a bat file and use the same command (e.g. `meshlabserver -i input.obj -o output.obj filter.mlx`) for different files. How do you do this with python?

Comment: If you want to use input and output filenames as arguments, just replace 'input.ply' by sys.args[1] and 'output.ply' by sys.args[2] in above script. Then write same batch file but execute the script instead meshlabserver

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! So call it with: `python test.py in.obj out.obj`? Apparently you also have to install the [PyMeshLab](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/PyMeshLab). Do you happen to know if you also need any other libraries apart from that (obviously apart from python)?

Comment: A couply of things 1. you also have to `import sys`, 2. use `sys.argv`, `sys.args` throws an error: `module 'sys' has no attribute 'args'`. 3. You have to use the 64bit version of python, the 32bit version just won't install pymeshlab.

Comment: True. I should have written `sys.argv` instead of `sys.args`

Comment: Incidentally MeshLab2020.09 is the last windows build with meshlabserver.exe