# MeshLab: How to process multiple obj files and save them to the disk

Tags: mesh, meshlab, pymeshlab

I have 50+ meshes to be processed. For each mesh, I need to import the obj file, apply the same filter and then save it to the disk.

My question is if there exists a method, either by clicking the mouse or by writing command lines, that can help get rid of processing them one by one manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own proposed problem with PyMeshLab, which is a python package that can be installed via `pip`. It is also easy to use. See its [documentation](https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#).

Answer (score 1):

In old versions of meshlab it included the meshlabserver program, which was used exactly for tbe use you want.
But it was discarded in meshlab 2020.12 in favour of PyMeshLab,

You can still use meshlab to apply any process and save the script as a mlx filter and then apply it to any mesh using this script. See [Where is Meshlabserver.exe in 2020.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65825861) for more details and a proposal to use max files